# Placeholder in javascript with val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can not understand Javascript language properly, I am trying to write inside placeholder but it is not working, here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>val demo</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myInputText').keyup(function() {
             $('#myOutputText2').val('placeholder="' + $(this).val() + '"');
             $('#myDIVTag').html('<b>' + $(this).val() + '</b>');
            });
        });     
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<input id="myInputText" type="text" name="post_title" size="79" placeholder="Enter title here" />
<p>Snippet Preview: <a href="#" id="myDIVTag"></a></p>
<input name="textfield2" type="text" id="myOutputText2" size="79" />


</body>
</html>
```

It is work perfectly but I want this in to placeholder mode.
Please help me.

Comment: Java is different from Javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/245062/1393766 -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/245069/1393766

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change an attribute, use [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) like

```
$('#myOutputText2').attr('placeholder',$(this).val());
```

**Update**

Since `placeholder` is a *native* HTML DOM property of input elements, it is better to use [**prop()**](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$('#myOutputText2').prop('placeholder',$(this).val());
```

For further reading, see [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Ok sir please wait I try that

Comment: This is not really correct - since a long time ago, the `.prop()` method should be used for setting DOM element properties, not `.attr()`.

Comment: @Pointy, do you mean `prop` should be used for all attributes? I thought it was for only `checked`, `disabled`, etc....

Comment: @AmmarCSE: OK SIR IT IS WORKING PROPERLY

Comment: @Pointy, this http://api.jquery.com/prop/ indicates that `prop` should be used with properties like `tagName, selectedIndex, nodeName` or boolean attributes

Comment: @AmmarCSE in my opinion `.prop()` should be used for properties that are directly exposed as properties on native DOM elements. Without jQuery, you (probably? I hope) wouldn't use `.setAttribute()` to set the value of things like that, so you should use `.prop()` in jQuery.

Comment: @AmmarCSE note that "placeholder" is a native DOM node property (in modern browsers that support "placeholder" at all), just like "nodeName", "tagName", etc.